# Disable compression for ReplayGain in Banshee

Tags: banshee, rhythmbox, replaygain

In Rhythmbox it's possible to disable compression for ReplayGain by unchecking a box in the settings of its ReplayGain plugin. The option is [described](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2010-February/msg01798.html) like the following:

> It provides configuration options for
>   [...] enabling or disabling
>   compression in order to prevent
>   clipping.

I wonder if there is such an option in Banshee? I have checked in its menu and glanced under Banshee in the dconf-editor without finding anything.

The reason I'm asking is after reading the following in the [ReplayGain specification](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=ReplayGain_specification#Reduced_gain):

> The audiophile user will not want any
>   compression or limiting on the signal.
>   In this case the only option is to
>   automatically and temporarily reduce
>   the pre-amp gain below the
>   user-selected setting for tracks where
>   clipping would otherwise occur.

Comment: I also notice that it's possible to set gain mode ('radio' or 'album') and adjust the pre-amp level in Rhythmbox's ReplayGain plugin. I can find neither of these settings in Banshee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Banshee currently does neither; it doesn't handle clipping at all, merely applying the needed gain.  This is somewhat less important given that it also doesn't expose the pre-amp knob so it's much less likely that the audio will clip in the first place.

So, the answer to the question “How do I disable compression for ReplayGain in Banshee” is: you do nothing; there is no compression for ReplayGain in Banshee ☺.

Banshee's ReplayGain support is largely influenced by what I care about and think makes sense from a UI perspective.  There are a bunch of knobs that could potentially be exposed, but I don't think make a huge amount of sense, or should be automatic (selection of *album* versus *track* gain, for example).

Clipping prevention is something that probably should be implemented, though.  At some point ☺.